# Datatables Multi Column Sorting

Tags: javascript, datatables

Is there anyway with DataTables to preform a multi-column sort where the secondary column is always sorted DSC irrespective to what sorting direction the primary column is sorted.

```
{
   targets: [ 0 ],
   orderData: [ 0, 12 ] //Column 12 needs to always be sorted DSC
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `orderFixed` for sorting like this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [ 0 ],
    orderData: [ 0, 12 ]
  }],

  orderFixed: [[ 12, "desc" ]]

  });
} );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect simple solution

Comment: happy to hear that :)